# Passing and displaying multiple values through FORM Method Post (from one page to another)

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

Table above (file a.php) is where i insert value to pass to another page, as you can see, i insert value **1** for **Lipstick**, value **10** for **test**, 
while output below (file b.php) you can see that it only takes value 10 for both. is there anyone that can assist me? for item lipstick, value should be 1.

[image]

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

---

below is my code for 1st page that has table, its called a.php, it will transfer value to b.php

**this is form in a.php, i intentionally put the symbol @@@ to help u where to look**

```
<form method="post" action="b.php" name="Logreg" style="padding-left:35px; padding-bottom:35px; font-size:14px;">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <th>Masa Masuk</th>
        <th>No. Kes</th>
        <th>Pegawai Serbuan</th>
        <th>Kategori Barang</th>
        <th>Perihal Barang</th>
        <th>Jenama Barang</th>
        <th>Kuantiti Barang</th>
        <th>Pilih Bilangan</th>
        <th>Rujukan Barang</th>
        <th>Pilih</th>
      </tr>
      <?php
      $sql = "select * from tbl_barang where view = 'y' &&  ";
      $sql = $sql."eks_id = '".$_GET['eks_id']."'";
      $result = $mydb->query($sql);
      while ($detailrow = $result->fetch_array()) {
      ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $detailrow['tarikhjam']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $detailrow['no_kes']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $detailrow['nama']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $detailrow['kategori_barang']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $detailrow['perihal_barang']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $detailrow['jenama_barang']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $detailrow['kuantiti_barang']; ?></td>
        @@@@@@@@@@@@<td><input type="text" name="kuantiti1" id="kuantiti1" size="1"></td>
        <td><?php echo $detailrow['rujukan_barang']; ?></td>


        <td> 
  <input name="barang_id[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $detailrow["barang_id"]; ?>"id="<?php echo $detailrow["barang_id"]; ?>"  onClick="toggle_2(this);" >
  &nbsp;&nbsp;<br /><br />

   </td>




      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
      </table> 
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-mm" value="Cetak Borang Serah Ekshibit" />

</form>
```

**settle with that, now below is my 2nd page which is b.php, i also place symbol @@@@@ in my coding below so u guys know where i suspected the problem in my code ... this is where both output 10 is displayed...**

```
<table style='width:100%' class='table table-striped table-bordered'>
    <tr>
    <th>Bil.</th>
    <th style='width:50%'>Perihal Barang</th>
    <th style='width:70%'>Kuantiti</th>
    </tr>     
     <?php 
    $count=count($_POST['barang_id']);
    for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
    {
    $a=$_POST['barang_id'][$i];
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_barang WHERE barang_id='$a'";

     $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_rekod WHERE no_kes IN 
  (SELECT * FROM tbl_barang WHERE barang_id = '$a')";

$sql5 = "select tbl_barang.no_kes,tbl_rekod.no_kes,tbl_rekod.lokasi_kejadian from tbl_rekod
INNER JOIN tbl_barang on tbl_rekod.no_kes = tbl_home.no_kes
where tbl_barang.barang_id ='$a'"; //test test test

    $result=$conn->query($sql);
    $result2=$conn->query($sql2);

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

     $ab=$row['perihal_barang'];
    $bc=$row['kuantiti_barang'];
    $ca=$row['jenama_barang']; 
    $cak=$row['akta'];


    ?>
     <tr> 
    <td align='center'><?php echo $io."." ?></td>
    <?php $io++; ?> <?php ?>
     <td align='center'><?php echo $ab ?></td>
     <td align='center'><!--<?php echo $bc ?> baru ubah 8.11.2017-->
     <?php 
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@ echo $_POST["kuantiti1"] // . " / " . $bc  ; ?>



     </td>
    </tr>
    <br/>
<?php

    }
    }   

 ?>
    </table>
```

i really hope my question is easy for people to understand..

Comment: paste your error here

Comment: @Bhargav i think theres no error, it just displays the same value.. however, comment below might make sense, i tried, but i got
 "Notice: Array to string conversion" when i tried to follow the suggestion

Comment: try with `print_r($_POST["kuantiti1"])` instead of `echo` and see whats the output

Comment: i tried as u suggested, and i insert value 1 for item test, value 1 for item lipstick. the output displayed was.... item test 11, item lipstick 11.. it somehow connects the two value..

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, your name=kuantiti1 can only contain one value.

Maybe you can try this:

```
<td><input type="text" name="kuantiti1[]" id="kuantiti1" size="1"></td>
```

Other step, you change the names dynamically

Comment: i tried change this, but i got error saying  "Notice: Array to string conversion" ... i should probably change something in my b.php as well i think?

Comment: Error on which page?